# see http request from unknown IP address

Tags: networking

I am currently using hyperterminal in order to try to communicate with an embedded device that is making http requests to my ip address. Is there a way that I can see the requests and respond if I don't know the IP address of the device? It is getting its IP address assigned from the network's DHCP server.

Answer (score 1):

Sure – that's how most web servers already work. But the key difference is that they're written to *accept* incoming connections, while HyperTerminal can only make outgoing ones, and if the device is "making HTTP requests to your address" then it's also trying to connect to you, *not* waiting for you to connect to it.

In other words, you'll need either an actual web server like [Apache2](https://www.apachelounge.com/download/), or at least some tool capable of listening for connections – like netcat (running `nc -l -p 80`) or perhaps a custom [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/) script. (Python also comes with a small HTTP server that takes a single command to start.) Perhaps there are also easier [Windows-specific tools](https://www.google.com/search?q=small%20windows%20web%20server) that I don't know of.